# How can I execute my tests in a different directory on CircleCI?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm running my continuous integration on CircleCI, and have a hard dependency in my tests that they must be run from `/vagrant`.

How can I copy my files there, and execute all my tests from there?

Thanks